# Using google cloud dataflow PubSubIO, when does the read of the message get acknowledged?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to delay acknowledgement until the subgraph (everything below the PubSubIO.Read) is successfully processed?

For example, we are **streaming** reads from a google pubsub subscription and then writing a file to GCS and in another branch we are writing to BigQuery using BigQueryIO.Write...

We do see that if an exception occurs it will retry indefinitely, since we are in streaming mode.  However, if we cancel the job and redeploy with a code change, the message is not reprocessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acknowledgement will be made once the message is durable persisted somewhere in the Dataflow pipeline.  If you want to make changes to a pipeline without losing in-flight data, use the Update feature instead of Cancel: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline

Comment: Is it possible to gracefully stop a Pipeline execution guaranteeing that I do not lose data that was already read off of the subscription but not fully processed?

Comment: That feature is called Drain, and is coming soon.  It will allow you to drain out all data in a running pipeline, including data that is buffered waiting for windows to be complete.