# How does PubSubIO determine reading speed when using DataflowRunner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

**Question** about how PubSubIO works in DataflowRunner using `AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED`: How does PubSubIO determine how fast should it pull the subscription(i.e. pull frequncy and number of messages in each pull)? I wonder if that has to do with the time between pulling the message and sending the acknowledgement?

**Background**: I'm running a pipeline that pulls down messages from PubSub and send it to a 3rd party vendor. The question came from an interesting behaviour I observed when I was running the pipeline under 2 different setup.

The original setup is to process everything under the global window, and according to the information I got from [project.locations.jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs/get), all DoFn was merged into a single step. This setup however suffers from a autoscale problem, where the dataflow job can autoscale to multiple workers, but the overall throughput was not increased. Large number of `extendAcknowledgeDeadline` request was also fired due to the fact that acknowledgement only happen at [`completeBundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727106/when-does-dataflow-acknowledge-a-message-of-batched-items-from-pubsubio).

The second setup is to add a `MapElement`, a `GroupByKey`, and a `ParDo` that first map the string message to KV where both key and value are the message string, then `GroupByKey` over a fixed window of 1 sec, and final parse the KV back to string, right after `PubSubIO.readStrings`. This was suggested by the [Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization) to break the fusion optimization, making. It also solved the autoscale issue in the original setup, as well as improved throughput of a single worker. Message in this setup will be acknowledged almost immediately.

This observation leads me to wonder if the `PubSubIO.read` throughput is determined by the how fast it takes to reach acknowledgement of the bundle, e.g. there are fixed number of connections to PubSub, and each connection won't be released to a new pull until the acknowledgement of the previously pulled bundle.