# How to Crash/Stop DataFlow Pub/Sub Ingestion on BigQuery Insert Error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am searching for a way to make a Google DataFlow job stop ingesting from Pub/Sub when a (specific) exception happens.

The events from Pub/Sub are JSON read via `PubsubIO.Read.Bound<TableRow>` using `TableRowJsonCoder` and directly streamed to BigQuery with
`BigQueryIO.Write.Bound`.
(There is a `ParDo` inbetween that changes the contents of one field and some custom partitioning by day happening, but that should be irrelevant for this purpose.)

When there are fields in the events/rows ingested from PubSub that are not columns in the destination BigQuery table, the DataFlow job logs IOExceptions at run time claiming it could not insert the rows, but seems to acknowledge these messages and continues running.

What I want to do instead is to stop ingesting messages from Pub/Sub and/or make the Dataflow job crash, so that alerting could be based on the age of oldest unacknowledged message. At the very least I want to make sure that those Pub/Sub messages that failed to be inserted to BigQuery are not ack'ed so that I can fix the problem, restart the Dataflow job and consume those messages again.

I know that one suggested solution for handling faulty input is described here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow

I am also aware of this PR on Apache Beam that would allow inserting the rows without the offending fields:
https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/1778

However in my case I don't really want to guard from faulty input but rather from programmer errors, i.e. the fact that new fields were added to the JSON messages which are pushed to Pub/Sub, but the corresponding DataFlow job was not updated. So I don't really have faulty data, I rather simply want to crash when a programmer makes the mistake not to deploy a new Dataflow job before changing anything about the message format.

I assume it would be possible to (analogue to the blog post solution) create a custom `ParDo` that validates each row and throws an exception that isn't caught and leads to a crash.

But ideally, I would just like to have some configuration that does not handle the insert error and logs it but instead just crashes the job or at least stops ingestion.

Comment: _"So I don't really have faulty data, I rather simply want to crash when a programmer makes the mistake not to deploy a new Dataflow job before changing anything about the message format."_ - taking a step back here, why don't you simply enforce an update to the Dataflow pipeline in your deployment pipeline when someone makes a change? I assume you've got some sort of integration/unit tests happening?

Comment: Not for the pipeline, no. It's rather slim and only uses of the shelf components, more or less. And testing it on synthetic data would be just as prone to forgetting changes as the initial setup, just with more overhead, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a ParDo with a DoFn which sits before the BQ write. The DoFn would be responsible to get the output table schema every X mins and would validate that each record that is to be written matches the expected output schema (and throw an exception if it doesn't).

```
Old Pipeline:
PubSub -> Some Transforms -> BQ Sink

New Pipeline:
PubSub -> Some Transforms -> ParDo(BQ Sink Validator) -> BQ Sink
```

This has the advantage that once someone fixes the output table schema, the pipeline will recover. You'll want to throw a good error messaging stating whats wrong with the incoming PubSub message.

Alternatively, you could have the `BQ Sink Validator` instead output messages to a PubSub DLQ (monitoring its size). Operationally you would have to update the table and then re-ingest the DLQ back in as an input. This has the advantage that only bad messages block pipeline execution.

Comment: This is what I meant with
"I assume it would be possible to (analogue to the blog post solution) create a custom ParDo that validates each row and throws an exception that isn't caught and leads to a crash."

It was just confusing to me that messages are acknowledged even if the BigQuery inserts fail (which if I understand this correctly means the messages are persisted somewhere in the pipeline according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020415/1935326)). I wondered if this could be avoided by proper configuration, either by not ACK'ing or by crashing.

Comment: Dataflow streaming pipelines will retry forever (not currently configurable to do anything else), they currently do not cancel/fail automatically based upon failures. Canceling the pipeline requires an explicit call to be made to Dataflow by a user (either from outside or within the pipeline, e.g. from the BQ Sink Validator).

Comment: Dataflow splits up the pipeline into many segments so the messages are ACK'd as soon as they enter the pipeline, since each of these segments are independent, it is not performant to track every source PubSub messages by the pipeline and have the messages NACK'd automatically if something fails. This is not generally feasible due to users producing multiple outputs for a single input (multi output DoFn), and also that multiple inputs may produce a single output (combiners).

Comment: So the `BQ Sink Validator` would not keep the pipeline from ACKing the messages, it would just retry validating the message forever and thus not lose it. To contrast, the BQ Sink would not retry but just drop the message. Is that correct?

But this would also mean that I can not drain the pipeline during such a scenario?

Could I cancel the pipeline from within the exception handling code?

Comment: The pipeline would still ACK the messages but the messages would not be lost since they would be stuck in the retry loop not losing it. To my knowledge, the BQ sink doesn't drop messages and will get stuck retrying indefinitely as well. Yes, you can cancel the pipeline when it is "stuck". No, you can not drain the pipeline because it will continuously fail. You can always create a dead letter queue where you send bad messages to instead of throwing exceptions from within the pipeline to keep the pipeline running allowing for a successful drain.